# Run siege on WSL2 against service running in Windows

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have a Spring application running in Windows on localhost:8080.

Now I want to run "siege" against it. I know how to translate the hostname so that I can access it from WSL, e.g.

```
ping NUKY.local
```

works as expected:

```
aui@NUKY:~$ ping NUKY.local
PING NUKY (172.30.80.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from NUKY (172.30.80.1): icmp_seq=1 ttl=128 time=0.321 ms
64 bytes from NUKY (172.30.80.1): icmp_seq=2 ttl=128 time=0.728 ms
```

Running siege with the following command yields errors:

```
aui@NUKY:~$ siege -c 1 -r 1 http://NUKY.local:8080/products/123
** SIEGE 4.0.4
** Preparing 1 concurrent users for battle.
The server is now under siege...[error] A non-recoverable resolution error for NUKY.local
: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

In a Windows shell I can execute:

```
> curl http://localhost:8080/products/123
{"productId":"123","title":"Some random title"}
```

In a WSL shell I can execute:

```
> curl http://NUKY.local:8080/products/123
{"productId":"123","title":"Some random title"}
```

How can I make siege resolve the Windows service and stress-test it?

Comment: So `curl http://localhost:8080/products/123` is working again *localhost* in WSL?  That's odd - I would think you would need `curl http://NUKY.local:8080/products/123`.  That makes me think that it might be WSL1, but then you say that `ping NUKY.local` is working, which should only be the case from WSL2.

Comment: Ah, sorry, my bad... I had added that "and in WSL" part without looking at the curl command. I fixed it now..

Comment: @user68186 Just a heads-up that my answer was *wrong* and now deleted.  I'll try to provide an update answer if someone else doesn't figure it out first.

Comment: And it turns out that the root cause appears to be in siege with mDNS.  Nothing specific to WSL or Windows going on here, other than mDNS is a common way to resolve the Windows IP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apologies for the previous off-base answer -- I made a wrong assumption on that.  I've now tested `siege` on Ubuntu on WSL and can reproduce this behavior myself.

It *looks* to be a name resolution issue, but I haven't dug in yet enough on the source to confirm.  But `siege` is definitely not resolving the mDNS name `$(hostname).local` (in your case `NUKY.local`).

I can make this work using this form (generic version):

```
siege -c 1 -r 1 http://$(dig -p 5353 $(hostname).local +short):8080/products/123
```

Explanation:

- Obtain the mDNS name using `$(hostname).local`.  You can, of course, skip this part and simply hardcode the Windows hostname as you are doing in your example (e.g. `NUKY.local`).
- Use `dig` to lookup the mDNS (port 5353) IP for that hostname

Of course, if there's some problem with the `dig` lookup, you could always hardcode the IP itself into your `siege` URL.  That works as well for me.  It's just when `siege` tries to resolve the `.local` form itself that the problem seems to manifest.

Also, because WSL2 is on a "separate network" from the Windows host, I do still have to create a firewall rule in Windows for this, or it won't work for me.  For the built-in Windows Defender, I'm using something like (from PowerShell):

```
New-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "Spring App Testing" -InterfaceAlias "vEthernet (WSL)" -Direction Inbound -Protocol TCP -LocalPort 8080 -Action Allow
```

Because your `curl` command is working from WSL, I'm assuming this is already in place for you, or you have a more permissive firewall policy in the first place.

That rule is a bit specific, and perhaps "overly restrictive" (some would call it "best practice"), so you may want to relax it a bit.  That rule *both*:

- Restricts the port to TCP 8080
- Restricts the network interface to the WSL NIC

You may want drop one or the other so that either:

- 8080 is available to access from any device on your local network (or even when forwarded from another network)
- Or all connections from the WSL vNIC are accepted.

Of course, "best practice" would also be to drop the rule when you are done with it, using:

```
Remove-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "Spring App Testing"
```

---

Caveat -- I haven't tested this with a Spring app, of course.  But I'm assuming that the root cause is the same since I can reproduce what you are seeing even with a simple HTTP server created with Python on the Windows side.  Hopefully this isn't yet another wrong assumption on my part ;-).

Comment: Thanks a lot already! Would you be so kind and copy me that Windows Firewall command again?

Comment: @Tom Sure thing - I added it back into the answer.